# Echo variable first and assign variable values later in php

Tags: php, if-statement, global-variables, conditional-statements

I am echoing the $indicator before $total using if else condition.

But I am getting php error

> Notice: Undefined variable: indicator.

How I can achieve this without getting any error and get my result which will be yellow according to the if else condition. Is it possible?

```
<?php 

$total=6;
echo $indicator;
echo $total;

if($total<5) {
    $indicator="red";
} else if($total>7) {
    $indicator="green";
} else {
    $indicator="yellow";
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to echo the variable _after_ assigning a value to it? What value would you expect to be printed by `echo` when you haven't assigned one yet?

Comment: @SameerSashittal can you update what is your desired output??

Comment: @kranthi: Output which i want is yellow6

Comment: Before assigning the value to a variable. What are you expecting the output of `echo` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try like this

**UPDATE**

```
<?php 

    echo myFun();

function myFun(){
    $total=6;

    if($total<5){
        $indicator="red";
    }elseif($total>7){
        $indicator="green";
    }else{
        $indicator="yellow";
    }

    return $indicator = $indicator.$total;
}
```

Comment: My requirement is not achieved using this because i want to echo the variable at the top

Comment: @SameerSashittal then why don't you add if..else code at top of page ?

Comment: @kranthi : Output which i want is yellow6

Comment: @TarangP: My requirement is this only and i need yellow6 output

Comment: @TarangP: Thanks for the help but how can echo those value before if else condition is it possible?